# SharePoint HTTP/2 Support

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, 2019

HTTP/2 was introduced in IIS10 which gets shipped since Windows Server 2016. Is the HTTP/2 protocol officially supported in any OnPremises version of SharePoint?

Updating question according to Robs answer: Setting in IIS, which *might* be set if SharePoint doesn't support HTTP/2:
[image: HTTP/2 Setting in IIS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP/2 is not supported by SharePoint as HTTP/2 doesn't support authentication schemes like NTLM or Kerberos.

[When is HTTP/2 Not Supported?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#when-is-http2-not-supported)

Comment: `Windows authentication (NTLM/Kerberos/Negotiate) is not supported with HTTP/2. In this case IIS will fall back to HTTP/1.1.` So my linked setting seems to be irrelevant, as IIS will always fall back to 1.1 as long as Kerberos or NTLM are in place.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Connell recently wrote a blog post that discusses this: [SharePoint 2016, 2019 & SharePoint Online: Which Version of the SharePoint Framework Should You Install?](https://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/spfx-which-version-of-spfx-generator-to-install/)

[image: Blog post screen capture]

Comment: This answers my question partly (SPFx extensions). I wonder if SharePoint supports HTTP/2 at all (base-installation, IIS-setting, see updated question). Nevertheless: upvote, thanks!